# Python deg2num syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error, cloudmade

I am a newbie when it comes to programming and I am trying to convert coordinates into tile numbers for a map app I am working on using Python. The code I was given to do this goes like this:

```
import math
def deg2num(lat_deg, lon_deg, zoom):
lat_rad = math.radians(lat_deg)
n = 2.0 ** zoom
xtile = int((lon_deg + 180.0)/360.0*n)
ytile = int((1.0 - math.log(math.tan(lat_rad)+(1/math.cos(lat_rad)))/math.pi)/2.0*n)
return (xtile, ytile)
```

When I pass in my lat_deg, lon_deg and zoom values into the function parameters I keep getting syntax errors when I run the code.

Could someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the errors as well?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you pasted it wrong, your error here is the indentation.

```
import math
def deg2num(lat_deg, lon_deg, zoom):
    lat_rad = math.radians(lat_deg)
    n = 2.0 ** zoom
    xtile = int((lon_deg + 180.0)/360.0*n)
    ytile = int((1.0 - math.log(math.tan(lat_rad)+(1/math.cos(lat_rad)))/math.pi)/2.0*n)
    return (xtile, ytile)
```

Try that.]

Still don't see your problem, I ran your code:

```
import math
def deg2num(lat_deg, lon_deg, zoom):
    lat_rad = math.radians(lat_deg)
    n = 2.0 ** zoom
    xtile = int((lon_deg + 180.0)/360.0*n)
    ytile = int((1.0 - math.log(math.tan(lat_rad)+(1/math.cos(lat_rad)))/math.pi)/2.0*n)
    return (xtile, ytile)
```

Using the same numbers you stated:

```
>>> print deg2num(40.22621608040184, 21.402665376663208, 10)
(572, 386)
>>>
```

Comment: I posted it wrong. The indentation is the same. Am still getting a "invalid syntax" notice.

Comment: It says: File "/Users/siyafrica/Desktop/assignment_0/lonlat_converter.py", line 2
    def deg2num(40.22621608040184, 21.402665376663208, 10):
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
logout

Comment: @Siya Edited my comment instead of replying for readability. I'm unsure of your problem here, the syntax is fine, it's not running on any modules apart from math. Either you're calling it wrong, or your python installation is bad, unless it's something else I can't think of.